# Remove multiple spaces from list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given list:

```
>>> l1 = ['1,  A Ab','2,B Bc ','3, C Cd ']
```

> 1. First element is having 2 spaces before `A Ab`.
> 2. Second element is having 1 space after `B Bc`.
> 3. Third element is 1 space each side of `C Cd`.

Want to remove n numbers of spaces occures before/after the element values.

Expected Result:

```
['1,A Ab','2,B Bc','3,C Cd']
```

My try:

```
>>> import re
>>> l2 = [re.sub(r"\s{2,}", "", s) for s in l1]
>>> l2
['1,A Ab', '2,B Bc ', '3, C Cd ']
```

Still getting spaces in second and third element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
l1 = ['1,  A Ab','2,B Bc ','3, C Cd ']
print( [",".join(map(str.strip, i.split(","))) for i in l1] )
```

**Output:**

```
['1,A Ab', '2,B Bc', '3,C Cd']
```

Comment: Third element still have space before the `C Cd`.

Comment: Updated snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it uses *list comprehension*.

```
>>> l1 = ['1,  A Ab','2,B Bc ','3, C Cd ']
>>>
>>> l1 = [",".join([s.strip() for s in item.split(",")]) for item in l1]
>>>
>>> l1
['1,A Ab', '2,B Bc', '3,C Cd']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same,

```
import re
l1 = ['1,  A Ab','2,B Bc ','3, C Cd ']
new_list = [re.sub(', +',',', i).strip() for i in l1]
```

Output

```
['1,A Ab', '2,B Bc', '3,C Cd']
```

Comment: It's not same as expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import re
l1 = ['1,  A Ab','2,B Bc ','3, C Cd ']
l2 = [re.sub(r"\s{2,}|(?<=,)\s|\s$","",s) for s in l1]
l2
```